# Laptop switches between "discharging" and "fully charged" when charging via thunderbolt port

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, thinkpad

I have two options to charge my laptop: (i) via the normal charging port or (ii) via the thunderbolt port. Charging via the normal charging port works fine, but when I charge through the thunderbolt port (via docking station or simply power cable) I get the notification "charging" and then "fully charged" and then "charging" again and so on. It never stops.

My Laptop is a Thinkpad T490 and I am running Manjaro 21.2.0 and the 5.10.79-1 Linux kernel.

When I look at journalctl I see the following during these notifications:

```
Nov 30 21:16:13 findme tlp[925608]: Warning: systemd-rfkill.socket is not masked, radio device switching may not work as configured.
Nov 30 21:16:13 findme tlp[925608]: >>> Invoke 'systemctl mask systemd-rfkill.socket' to correct this.
```

Running the requested command works, but does not change anything.

EDIT: when the laptop is not fully charged it switches between "charging" and "running on battery" instead I think. And it does not actually charge the laptop.